# Is is possible to use ShareThis in a PhoneGap app?

Tags: iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, sharethis

I've checked the plugin repository on github, and there does not appear to be a plugin already written for ShareThis. I think this means I would have to install the mobile version of ShareThis written in Objective-C. Is there a way to make that work?

Comment: Why can't you use the same methods that you would for a web site? They're based on JavaScript, and so is Phonegap.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. There's a lot better resources on why then I can provide here/now.

Comment: Have you looked at the official FB plugin? URL here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12466464/1158376 You can use this plugin without having to *write* any Objective C, but you will have to use Xcode and do some configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that you would need to write a plugin to interface between the ShareThis iOS API and PhoneGap.

Looks like a pretty straight forward API... shouldn't bee too hard.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS

Also, just looking at some of the simpler plugins in the GitHub repo you should be able to get one working for this.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a way to avoid working in objective-c. This is the reason why I'm using PhoneGap in the first place (I don't know any objective-c).