# Cordova/Phonegap Social Sharing

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

I'm looking for an easy solution for sharing inside of a cordova/phonegap application. I'm looking to add facebook, twitter and email sharing. Much like this app has: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mars-hill-church/id322993145?mt=8. If you click through the sermons you can actually share an individual sermon.

I've tried using this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/. I was going to launch the share post inside of an iframe but unfortunately facebook doesn't allow you to load within iframe.

Preferably I want the share portion to stay inside the app as much as possible without launching safari. However, I would settle for a facebook button (Customized look), that I could click on and it launched me out of the app into safari to share a story.

Cordova 1.8
IOS 5
JQuery 
Jquery Mobile

Comment: You able to solve this? I'm having the same problem. :)

Comment: Unfortunately not, if you find out any solutions, let me know and I'll do the same.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the official plugin for Facebook Connect in Apache Cordova/PhoneGap? The code is hosted at
https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect 
and there's a press release at 
http://phonegap.com/2011/08/30/get-the-new-phonegap-facebook-platform-plugin/.

This sounds like what you're after, but I haven't tried it myself yet.

Comment: Thanks for your help here. I've tried using the plugin above and it seems to be the right fit. However, I'm getting some errors that I'm unsure how to fix. Wondering if you might be able to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483751/davejohnson-phonegap-facebook-plugin-issues

Comment: If or when I try this plugin myself, I will share the experience here.