# DaveJohnson Phonegap/Facebook plugin issues

Tags: ios5, cordova, xcode4.3, phonegap-plugins

I'm try to get facebook integration into my cordova 1.8.1 application. I've tried several different plugins only to find that they don't support cordova 1.8. DaveJohnson's Plugin supposedly supports cordova 1.8 but I'm having issues with it. I'm getting a lot of errors when I click the login button that comes in the example index page:

```
2012-09-18 14:44:00.327 LCBCChurch[4597:707] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2012-09-18 14:44:00.337 LCBCChurch[4597:707] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2012-09-18 14:44:02.625 LCBCChurch[4597:707] CDVPlugin class FacebookConnectPlugin (pluginName: org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect) does not exist.
2012-09-18 14:44:02.629 LCBCChurch[4597:707] ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
2012-09-18 14:44:02.630 LCBCChurch[4597:707] FAILED pluginJSON = {"className":"org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect","methodName":"init","arguments":["org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect1","appid"]}
2012-09-18 14:44:02.632 LCBCChurch[4597:707] CDVPlugin class FacebookConnectPlugin (pluginName: org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect) does not exist.
2012-09-18 14:44:02.634 LCBCChurch[4597:707] ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
2012-09-18 14:44:02.635 LCBCChurch[4597:707] FAILED pluginJSON = {"className":"org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect","methodName":"getLoginStatus","arguments":["org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect2"]}
2012-09-18 14:44:16.426 LCBCChurch[4597:707] CDVPlugin class FacebookConnectPlugin (pluginName: org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect) does not exist.
2012-09-18 14:44:16.428 LCBCChurch[4597:707] ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
2012-09-18 14:44:16.429 LCBCChurch[4597:707] FAILED pluginJSON = {"className":"org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect","methodName":"login","arguments":["org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect3","email"]}
```

I even followed a video tutorial to the T, but am getting these failures. Does anyone know what any of these mean and how I can fix them. Would truly appreciate any help you can provide, thanks!

------ UPDATE -------

I think it was the way that I loaded the .m and .h files. I didn't use "references" and I added it as a target.

However now I'm getting another error. The login button launches me over to facebook but now I get an error in fb "An error occurred. Please try again later." Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have added the facebook id at the eventlistener code snippet(right at the end of the index html.)

Comment: Thank you! That fixed that error, however now I'm getting another error: "LCBC Phone App is misconfigured for facebook login. Press Oka to go back to the application without connecting it to facebook." Any idea what I "misconfigured"?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add an entry to Cordova.plist. "org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect," for the key and FacebookConnectPlugin for the value.

Then, make sure you already have create a Facebook app and put your bundle ID in the Native IOS app section. Don't forget to enable login too.